# What are the iPhone app-name restrictions? (And [where] are they documented?!)

Tags: iphone, distribution, adhoc

It took me 2 days (and a lot of head/wall pounding) to finally discover that the reason ad-hoc distribution wasn't working for me was because my app-name had UTF-8 characters.  I'm still boggling over how such a widely international platform like the Apple iPhone can prohibit this.

*i.e.*, if my app were a Chinese game of Go, am I not allowed to call it "Go! (圍棋)"?!

Anyway, I'm wondering...

- Is this an actual limitation, or a bug in the ad-hoc process?
- Are there other restrictions on app-name (perhaps chars that don't play well with unix, like ?, *, !, &, etc.)
- Is any of this documented, anywhere?  (If so, where :)
- Can anyone point to an example of an app in the app-store with UTF-8 chars (particularly Japanese/Chinese) in the name?

Thanks!

(I know: it looks like several questions, but they really are all related!)

Comment: I can't answer your question confidently, but the way I look at it you may as well just assume you are limited to ASCII and Apple will never fix it.  The sooner you accept that the happier you will be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out (according to DTS), it's a bug in the way iTunes handles ad-hoc distribution.  This problem is specific to ad-hoc -- my developer distribution works fine, and I'm told the app-store will handle it fine, too -- it's just ad-hoc distribution (the common mechanism for things like beta-testing.)

In part, DTS's response was:

"I've been able to reproduce it. I've also confirmed it only appears to be an issue for Ad Hoc distribution, so I'm inclined to believe it's a bug in iTunes (I tested in 8.0.1, the latest).

I'm awaiting a ruling from iPhone OS engineering on this, but I would recommend you file a bug with your test case app."

(Hey, do I get to vote-up my own answer?  Is that cheating? :D)

(Answer: no you can't.  So I guess it would be ;)

Answer (score 1):

OSX in general supports UTF8 natively, throughout Cocoa to the Filesystem.

An example in 日本語:
http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=294753911&mt=8

If I had to guess, you probably have to name your application something in ASCII but you can make the application title UTF8. Not sure though.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the CFBundleDisplayName key in Info.plist?