# App Store Application name

Tags: app-store

can we use colon in my application name which is going to be submit in app store like ABC:abc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be no restrictions on the range of allowed characters.

See

- [What are the iPhone app-name restrictions? (And [where] are they documented?!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266554/what-are-the-iphone-app-name-restrictions-and-where-are-they-documented)
- [App Store Submission Tips](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/news/appstoretips/)